# How to create missing rules event when user flags a statuses updates?

Tags: 7, rules, flags, notifications, message-subscribe

**The problem:**

Rules events are missing. **EVENT 1. user flagged a statuses** and **EVENT 2. user flagged a fbss_comment**. Everything is available, just need to add these events. Status updates are created by [statuses module](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses). I want to log both events mentioned above using [message module](https://www.drupal.org/project/message), but I Cannot unless and until this event is created. Conditions and actions are available by default.

**Important Note:**

> [Statuses](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses) is not compatible with [flag 3](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag). It works with flag
>   2. When you install flag 2, status updates will show "like" button in status updates and status comments. Not only this, but you will also
>   be able to see status updates of users you are following, in your
>   status stream, when flagged with "follow" flag. Moreover, if you see
>   rules conditions and actions, you will find out that **"fbss_comment
>   is flagged"** and **"statuses is flagged"** and similarly actions
>   **"flag a statuses"** and **"flag a fbss_comment"** are available. I am getting a feeling that the solution might be hidden within the
>   statuses module folder and its submodules. Just need someone who has
>   an eye to see it. Someone said, **"Everything is possible with
>   drupal"**

**What I tried?**

Starting with "user flagged a fbss_comment" event, I went to file **fbss_comments_rules.rules.inc** in the sub-module fbss_comments. Under `function fbss_comments_rules_rules_event_info()` I pasted,

```
'fbss_comments_flag' => array(
      'label' => t('User flags a comment on a status'),
      'group' => t('Statuses Comments'),
      'variables' => array(
        'comment' => array(
          'type' => 'fbss_comment',
          'label' => t('The status comment.'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Then under `function fbss_comments_rules_add_action` I added,

```
function fbss_comments_rules_flag_action($cid, $sid, $message, $uid) {
  fbss_comments_flag_comment($cid, $sid, $message, empty($uid) ? $GLOBALS['user']->uid : $uid);
}
```

Note: I do not know what I was doing. I just did it as a trial and error.

**Message type Export**

```
{
  "name" : "scomments_liked",
  "description" : "Status comments liked",
  "argument_keys" : [ "@scomments_liked_user", "!scomments_liked_statuses_url" ],
  "argument" : [],
  "category" : "message_type",
  "data" : {
    "token options" : { "clear" : 0 },
    "purge" : { "override" : 0, "enabled" : 0, "quota" : "", "days" : "" }
  },
  "language" : "",
  "arguments" : null,
  "message_text" : { "und" : [
      {
        "value" : "@scomments_liked_user liked your comment on the \u003Ca href=\u0022!scomments_liked_statuses_url\u0022\u003EStatus Update\u003C\/a\u003E",
        "format" : "plain_text",
        "safe_value" : "@scomments_liked_user liked your comment on the \u003Ca href=\u0022!scomments_liked_statuses_url\u0022\u003EStatus Update\u003C\/a\u003E"
      }
    ]
  },
  "rdf_mapping" : []
}
```

**Rules Export**

```
{ "rules_statuses_comments_flag" : {
    "LABEL" : "Statuses comments flag",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "statuses" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "fbss_comments_rules", "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "fbss_comments_flag" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "fbss_comments_rules_load_action" : {
          "USING" : { "cid" : [ "comment:cid" ] },
          "PROVIDE" : { "comment_loaded" : { "comment_loaded" : "Loaded status comment" } }
        }
      },
      { "entity_query" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "user",
            "property" : "uid",
            "value" : [ "comment-loaded:uid" ],
            "limit" : "1"
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_fetched" : { "entity_fetched" : "Fetched entity" } }
        }
      },
      { "entity_create" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "message",
            "param_type" : "scomments_liked",
            "param_user" : [ "entity-fetched:0" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "entity-created:arguments:scomments-liked-user" ],
          "value" : "[site:current-user]"
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "entity-created:arguments:scomments-liked-statuses-url" ],
          "value" : "[comment:comment-status-url]"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Rules Export based on Nial Murphy's answer**

```
{ "rules_user_flagged_statuses" : {
    "LABEL" : "User flagged statuses update",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "statuses" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "fbss_rules", "rules", "flag" ],
    "ON" : { "flag_flagged_like" : [] },
    "DO" : [
      { "fbss_rules_load_action" : {
          "USING" : { "sid" : [ "flagged-status:sid" ] },
          "PROVIDE" : { "status_loaded" : { "status_loaded" : "Loaded status" } }
        }
      },
      { "entity_query" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "user",
            "property" : "uid",
            "value" : [ "status-loaded:sender" ],
            "limit" : "1"
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_fetched" : { "entity_fetched" : "Fetched entity" } }
        }
      },
      { "entity_create" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "message",
            "param_type" : "flagged_status",
            "param_user" : [ "entity-fetched:0" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "entity-created:arguments:statuses-flagged-user" ],
          "value" : "[flagging-user:name]"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Currently, what flag events are available? can you post a screenshot?

Comment: see comments below

Comment: Added a rules export to my question based on Niall Murphy's answer

Comment: Hey Umair, I tried to import your (1st) rule, but it fails with an error like so: "***Integrity check for the imported configuration failed. Error message: Data selector <em class="placeholder">comment:cid</em> for parameter <em class="placeholder">cid</em> is invalid..***". Any idea why? And how I can resolve that import error?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I do not know why. Are you using the niall's version of statuses or the original version? I was having this problem when I installed niall's ver to my existing site. This is what it is showing on that site's rules page. Unknown event "fbss_comments_flag"                 "Error: Data selector comment:cid for parameter cid is invalid". I guess this is because the niall's ver does not work with the statuses comments. That rule was generated with the original statuses and flag 2. See above "What I tried" section of the question.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222383/how-to-create-a-rule-to-combine-the-terms-of-2-fields-to-create-a-new-term-store/222485#222485), which described a similar Rules import issue (within things to be aware of). I think that is also what causes my import problem. I am using flag 2, nothing related to Niall's answer. Try to import the exported rule with a slightly changed machine name, eg add "2"  to it, I bet you will have the same import problem. Can you add screenprint(s) of your rule so I can try to recreate the rule via Rules Ui myself?

Comment: Continued ... Your own import error with Niall's rule is about sure due to the same Rules import problem. And about your last comment: that is a different question, not allowed to be added somehow in this question (it would invalidate existing answers). Maybe create a new question about that (with link to this one as "followup"?), something like this "It seems there is no (easy) way to solve my original question, so now I want to try so and so" ...

Comment: [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gz5v6gq7q6h57wa/Untitled.png?dl=0) This was on my previous test site that is why it is showing error

Answer (score 3):

***Preface - start***

This answer assumes you're using the current version of [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag), i.e. 7.x.-3.x. Though a comment below this answer states:

> Statuses is not compatible with flag 3. It works with flag 2. When you install flag 2, status updates will show "like" button in status updates and status comments. Not only this, but you will also be able to see status updates of users you are following, in your status stream, when flagged with "follow" flag.

***Preface - stop***

---

---

I'm afraid there is **no way** to create either of those Rules Events (as in your question):

- a status update is flagged.
- a status comment is flagged.

At least not if you're using version 7.x.-3.x. of [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag). Read on to understand why ...

Use the Rules UI to have a look at the available Rules Events, located within the ***Flag*** group of events. The number of entries you will find there will vary, but each of them is similar to something like this:

> ***A `thing-ie` has been flagged, under "`something`"***.

Some more details:

- ***`thing-ie`*** refers to a Drupal **entity**, like node, user, group, message.
- ***`something`*** refers to the **title** of the flag, which you specify when you define (create or edit) your flag in administration.

But when you ***add*** a new flag, using `/admin/structure/flags/add`, the very first thing you are enforced to do is "*Select the type of flag to create*" (which will become your ***`thing-ie`***). And the possible options you can select are all **entities**, such as node, user, group, message, comment, etc. However, something that contains "status" cannot be selected, simply because it's missing in that list (and it is missing, because the [Statuses](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses) module does NOT create entities).

If however, you'd select "comment" in that list (which sounds close to "status comment", worth trying), then in the next step (at `admin/structure/flags/add/comment`), you get another list within **Bundles**, where you can select the bundles that such flag may be used for. The available options in that list are like "ABC comments", whereas "ABC" corresponds to each of your content types. So this won't work either (there is nothing related to "Statuses" that can be selected).

What is above should not be a surprise, simply because of what's mentioned on the Flag's project page (I added the bold markup here):

> ... Using this module, the site administrator can provide any number of flags for nodes, comments, users, and any other type of **entity**.

Again, the [Statuses](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses) module does NOT create entities, and therefor there is no way to come up with something like:

> ***A Status (= `thing-ie`) has been flagged, under "Some status related title" (= `something`)***.

So for all reasons mentioned above, I think you're asking the wrong question:

- You won't be able to use the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module to flag a ***Status***.
- Try to think of anything else related to the [Statuses](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses) module that you can use for creating some custom Rules Events that you can use to create a log about something that happened related to Status updates or Status comments.

Maybe this helps you somehow: there are 4 Rules Events available for Statuses and 3 Rules Events for Status Comments. Try to use any of those Rules Events, to do what you'd want to do as extra Rules Actions, similar to what you have in mind if there was an answer to your question.

Sorry, but I'm afraid this is as good as it gets.

Comment: Statuses is not compatible with flag 3. It works with flag 2. When you install flag 2, status updates will show "like" button in status updates and status comments. Not only this, but you will also be able to see status updates of users you are following, in your status stream, when flagged with "follow" flag.

Comment: Moreover, if you see rules conditions and actions, you will find out that "fbss_comment is flagged" and "statuses is flagged" and similarly actions "flag a statuses" and "flag a fbss_comment" are available. I am getting a feeling that the solution might be hidden within the statuses module folder and its submodules. Just need someone who has an eye to see it.

Comment: the rules events I am looking for, are available when I go to "Triggers" module settings, but there are not many actions to choose from. Any idea?

Comment: started a bounty

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens  Umair may be interested in a file I've uploaded to Google Drive. His mind may be put at ease if you vouch for me. I can remove all mentions of you and the file afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Umair, have you looked at the patches in [drupal.org/node/1787930](http://drupal.org/node/1787930) and [drupal.org/node/1311468](http://drupal.org/node/1311468) and *maybe* some others ? I got flag 3 working with the status + rules, but not the comments. It could be possible but I didn't want the comments flaggable so I didn't spend any time trying.

For some reason, I can't recreate the order of patches that got me my working module, [here it is to download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B46JrWR9Xu7QaC1YOFRGcXg0Z2c/view?usp=sharing). It lets me create a new flag type for Status which integrates with Rules and then Message. I just tested it on a clean install and when a status was liked, the action fired.

While I wouldn't particulary trust someone to give me a module of Google Drive, Pierre.Vriens can probably vouch for me not being a bad person and if you do wish to use it in production after testing, I'd encourage you to find the combination / order of patches that results in a 45kb statuses.module file and then work from there. From looking at the .info file, I seem to have to started with the Dev release.

Side-note: You should look at the example files included with the Message module. I have some extremely complex Message scenarios where Rules wasn't good enough and it would be good for you to be aware of the added possibilities.

Comment: Wow, sharing an entire module, that is really nice Niall! I have not looked at it in detail, but as per your various answers I've seen in the past, I would definitely give it a try as you described here. BTW, no need for any Mentions (or similar). And of course +1

Comment: If pierre trusts you then I trust you. In short, I simply have to install your module and it will solve my problem. right? Of course as you have mentioned above that it will not work on comments. Its ok. I did not understand the 3rd paragraph of your answer.

Comment: Yep. It's just a slightly changed Statuses module. Just enable it and any of its sub-modules that look like they'd be needed and clear the cache. Then, create a new flag for "status" and the default setting will add the flag to /statuses/all. I'm sure you can add it elsewhere no problem. Then create your rule to create the message. Hopefully, it will work as it did for me.

The third paragraph was just about re-creating the module as it is now by going through the patches but it's not necessary.

Comment: Ha Pierre, it was to perfect for the question to not share the patched module. I had the exact same problem as Umair around six months ago and it felt hopeless trying to get it to work!

Comment: So everything else will work as it does? for example the "follow" flag.

Comment: Should do. Nothing else changed for me.

Comment: I am having the same problem I had before when I tried to use statuses with flag 3. What I did? Uninstalled statuses and its submodules and flag 2 as well. Installed your module and flag 3. What I am doing wrong? Should I install flag 2? Secondly, I was not able to enable the like flag, so I changed the entity type from "statuses" to "status" in fbss_flag.module file under function fbss_flag_flag_default_flags()

Comment: These events are showing in rules [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jrq2a9542qi9okn/event-shot.png?dl=0)

Comment: Moreover the required event "status flagged" is also showing in the list under flags

Comment: You don't enable the like flag, you create a new one for "status". And in rules, the event will be under Flags and called something like "A status had been flagged under "Like". Try that and report back.

Comment: Also try on a clean install with flag 3, rules and the module I posted.

Comment: I did a clean install and selected the event in rules. Now the problem is that when try to create a "condition" ([Not]Status was posted to own profile) and the "action" (Create new entity), I do not get the appropriate data selectors. In (Create new entity) "action", you have to select a data selector for "user for which to log message". Obviously "message" will be logged for the status owner. What is the problem?

Comment: I did it. Thanks to @Pierre.Vriens I applied what he taught me earlier, but I am not able to add a condition so that when a user flags his own status, the message is not logged.

Comment: The data selector in "condition" ([Not]Status was posted to own profile) is showing "flagged-status:". Even tried without colon. When I save, it says "The data type of the configured argument does not match the parameter's status requirement"

Comment: When I try to add the contextual filter "Statuses: Content from flagged users or the argument user" I get this error `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'drupal_7_52.flag_content' doesn't exist` This is the same error which I got previously when I tried to use official statuses module with flag 3. If I have these problems, I cannot use your module

Comment: @NiallMurphy I am waiting for your reply. I cannot use your module until and unless these problems are solved

Comment: Have you made any progress since posting? What view ae you trying to add the contextual filter to and what is the purpose of the view?