# What does Rules token "node:unchanged" mean?

Tags: nodes, rules

I am on Drupal 7 and I am using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to do some stuff.

I must say that I am not very used to using this module; there are few questions that need answers, such as the use of the *node:unchanged* token.

For example, when I set a rule with a data comparison as a condition, I have to give the name of the referred field; then, there is either *node:changed* or *node:unchanged*.

I am quite accustomed to using *node:changed*. What does *node:unchanged* mean?

Comment: "Un" is a negative prefix in English - if you understand what node:changed means, it's a struggle to see how you wouldn't understand what node:unchanged means. Is it literally just that you didn't know "un" negates the proceeding term in English?

Comment: Thanx @Clive. Sometimes I mix up things and it becomes hard to understand. It's clear now. Thank u.

Comment: No problem, I added an answer to clear it up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Terminology

"***`unchanged`*** refers to the value before something (eg, a field of entity user or node) gets updated (the old value that it used to be).

"***`changed`*** refers to the value after something (eg, a field of entity user or node) gets updated (the new value that it will become).

#### Examples

Have a look at my answers to these question for some typical usecases of it:

- [Monitoring field changes in custom content type](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/224093/39516)
- [How to implement admin verification for selected user profile fields?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/205608/39516)
- [How to include only an updated custom field in an email created using Rules?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/205493/39516)
- [How to use Rules to email users when any field(s) is changed in a node (and include the unchanged/changed values for that field)?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/228371/39516)

Answer (score 5):

"Unchanged" is literally the opposite of "changed" in this context. If you know what node:changed means, just reverse it for node:unchanged.

For reference, though:

- node:changed refers to a node after field or property data has been changed, following a node save
- node:unchanged refers to the same node, before field or property data has been changed.

The two are useful together for determining whether a particular field or property value has been changed on a node, and what the value went from/to, in a particular save operation.